# Git push issue related to branches

Tags: git, github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, git-push

I am new to Git and trying to commit and push a local jupyter notebook. There are two branches in my Github repository "master" and "develop" currently I have to work on "develop". In my Git bash, I have only one branch called "master". When I added and committed the file and tried to push it showed me these errors:

```
$ git push -u origin develop
error: src refspec develop does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

You said

> I have to work on "develop"

You also said

> In my Git bash, I have only one branch called "master"

These statements aren't *exactly* in conflict, as git is very flexible; but as a beginner you should start by learning the basic/typical usage.  When you fully understand that, you may from time to time recognize cases where a more "exotic" configuration would be useful, and that is the time to take advantage of git's flexibility.

So, if you're meant to be working in `develop`, then you should locally check out `develop`.  Assuming you've cloned from a remote that has a `develop` branch (and not added additional remotes), you should just be able to say

```
git checkout develop
```

and this will create the local `develop` branch, pointing to the same commit as the remote's `develop` (as of your most recent clone/fetch/pull).  Then you make your changes, and then when you say to push to develop git will know what you mean.  (In this case, you won't even need the `-u` option because the upstream would be set up for you.)

On the other hand, if your remote *doesn't* already have a `develop` branch, then you can create one locally

```
git checkout -b develop
```

Then you make your changes, and for the first push use

```
git push -u origin develop
```

Note that if you try to do it this way, but the remote already has a `develop` branch, you will likely get a "rejected" error when you push due to a non-fast-forward update.  This is the same problem you appear to have had when you tried to push your master state directly to develop (in comments on the other answer) and means that you're attempting a push that would erase history from the remote branch.

Comment: There were some helping comments by @Sajib yesterday and I can't see them. Why is it so?

Comment: @Nizam - Sajib's answer (and corresponding comments) is no longer visible because Sajib chose to delete it. Considering their advice was leading you progressively further from what you initially set out to do (in the name of addressing each error message as it arose) I think it was the correct thing for them to do; but my opinion aside, it was their choice. As it happens I have enough rep to see deleted answers, which is why I am able to answer your question; but in general if you have questions about a user's answers, you need to address them to *that* user.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Mark.